# HTC desire 530 battery drains fast

Tags: battery-life, htc-desire

I tried everything to prevent my battery from draining, but noting seams to help. I've tried a new battery, power saving apps, getting rid of apps. Is this a software issue? Would a rom help with the battery? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I have no straight answer, but a pointer: our [battery-life tag wiki](/tags/battery-life/info) lists a bunch of relevant (answered) questions which might help you. Please check and then let us know if it solved the issue (and what did it). Good luck!

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know

Comment: The least I could do for someone new – who might not be aware that many of our tags have such wiki page available :)